# evaluating lines from stdout

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a bash script that is executing a program in a loop.  I want to evaluate each line from the stdout and do something if it matches my condition.

I still want to be able to see stdout on the screen.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to **echo** the lines you are parsing?

Answer (score 22):

There are several variants of looping over input, but one possibility is thus:

```
my_cmd | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
    my_process "$line"
done
```

Comment: note that you can use multiplve variable names to read chunks into them (`| while read id number description; do echo $number: $id; done`)

Comment: To preserve whitespace, quote the variable: `echo "$line"; my_process "$line"`

Comment: Also, note that putting `while` in a pipeline means the while body executes in a sub-process. Depending on what `my_process` is, the OP might not want that, so: `while read -r line; do ...; done < <(my_cmd)`

Answer (score -1):

This should do what you want:

```
for string in "a" "b" "c"
do
    output=`echo ${string}`
    echo ${output}
    if [ ${output} == "b" ] ; then
        echo "do something"
    fi
done
```

Just replace the first echo with your program.

Comment: This is iterating on a list of string literals.  The question specifically asked for lines in STDOUT to be the iterable object.

Comment: Following works:

for string in `ls .`
do
  echo $string
done